# Plugin usage with nested subdocuments in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema in mongoose like this:

```
var subtopicSchema = new schema({
    name:String
})

var topicSchema = new schema({
   name:String,
    subtobpics:[subtopicSchema]
});

var subjectSchema = new schema({
    name:String,
    topics:[topicSchema]
})

var courseSchema = new schema({
    name:{type:String,unique:true},
    subjects:[subjectSchema]
});
```

And then I am using a '[unique validator plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator)' like this:

```
courseSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: 'unique' });
```

So here is what i want to achieve:

1. All courses should be unique
2. All subjects within a particular course needs to be unique
3. All topics within a particular subject to needs be unique
4. All subtopics within a particular topic to needs be unique

So the question is: Is the current setup gonna work for the above four requirements?

If yes, why?

If not, How?